# eXide not show any results on screen

Tags: database, xpath, xquery, exist-db, exide

I write this query in eXist-db (eXide):

```
doc("/db/libros/prueba.xhtml")/html/body/p/a/@href
```

Find two results:
Found 2 in 0.003s

But the screen does not show any

Input document is:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title> titulo </title>
</head>
<body>
<p class="clase1"> esto es un parrafo <a href="www.wikipedia.com"> wikipedia </a></p>
<p> otro parrafo <a href="www.youtube.com">youtube</a></p>
</body>
</html>
```

the system is

```
kernel : Linux 3.5.0-27-generic (x86_64)

Distribution Linux Mint 14 Nadia

eXist Version:  2.0
eXist Build:    20130207
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to put data() around. Have a look:

```
data(doc("file:/C:/Users/vgv/Desktop/Testing/Untitled1.xml")/html/body/p/a/@href)
```

output:

```
www.wikipedia.com www.youtube.com
```

Comment: Navin is correct.  Your query returns attribute nodes, but you want the string value of those nodes.  The data() function that Navin suggested would return the typed value of the attribute nodes, but the string() function might be more specific in getting the nodes' string value:  `doc("file:/C:/Users/vgv/Desktop/Testing/Untitled1.xml")/html/body/p/a/@href/string()`  This is really an XQuery issue, not one specific to eXide.